# Electron App: Call java jar

Tags: javascript, java, angular, electron

I have electron app (written in angular), is there any way hot execute java **jar** from the local filesystem?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I know of to do this would be to use Node's [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) feature to execute it like you would from the command line.